# set date to posixct without knowing origin

Tags: r

I have a datetime supplied in the  following format:

```
ex <-2008123118
```

and am trying to convert it to datetime format. I try:

```
mytime2 <- as.POSIXct(ex, format = "%Y%m%d%H")
```

but receive the error:

```
Error in as.POSIXct.numeric(ex, format = "%Y%m%d%H") : 
  'origin' must be supplied
```

The error seems straightfoward, but the only issue is what if I don't know the origin. For example, this part of my code will go into a much larger code that will process a number of files.

I would like my example to return:

```
2008-12-31 18:00
```

Is that possible?

Comment: It seems pretty clear that you do not want the version of as.POSIXct that depends upon using the origin. My answer was predicated on think that `2008123118`  was not meant to be a number but rather needed to be interpreted as `2008-12-31 18H`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two versions of `as.POSIXct` working behind the scenes, `as.POSIXct.numeric` and `as.POSIXct.character`, and you have tried to call both of them at once. Because that value is coming in as "numeric" it gets passed to `as.POSIXct.numeric` and that is actually the cause of the error here, because `as.POSIXct.numeric` has no detection algorithm for date-like values and also has no "format" parameter. Coerce it to "character and all is well:

```
> ex <-2008123118
> mytime2 <- as.POSIXct(as.character(ex), format = "%Y%m%d%H")
> mytime2
[1] "2008-12-31 18:00:00 PST"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example with `lubridate` with the `ymd_h` function:

```
library(lubridate)
ymd_h(ex)
[1] "2008-12-31 18:00:00 UTC"
```

here a base R solution

```
strptime(ex, format = "%Y%m%d%H")
[1] "2008-12-31 18:00:00 CET"
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way of doing it with base R?

Comment: But note that the time zone are different. You have to specify the right one for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code, in base R:

```
> ex <-2008123118
> as.POSIXct(strptime(ex, format = "%Y%m%d%H")) #this gives you additional seconds
"2008-12-31 18:00:00 EST"
> strftime(as.POSIXct(strptime(ex, format = "%Y%m%d%H")), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") #this gives your desired format
"2008-12-31 18:00"
```

Hope this helps.